# How to trigger a method in all pages request in Yii?

Tags: methods, yii, controller

In the header section of my website I want to show new message. I have a method that fetches new methods and return them.  The problem is that header section is in the`layout` section and I don't want to repeat one method in all of my controllers.

How to achieve this by not copying the method to all of my controllers? I want to trigger `newMessages()` method on every page request to gather new messages for logged in user. How to do this the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller overwrite the oOntroller class function beforeAction()

```
protected function beforeAction($event)
{
    $someResult = doSomething()
    if ($someResult == $someValue)
    {
        return true;         
    }
    else
    {
        return true;         
    }
}
```

The return value can be used to stop the request dead in its tracks. So if it returns false, the controller action is not called, and vice versa().

References : http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#beforeAction-detail

Comment: Thanks. I've handled it via ajax request, but your reply answers my question. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use import controller in another controller action. something like below

```
class AnotherController extends Controller
{
    public function actionIndex()
    {
            Yii::import('application.controllers.admin.YourController'); // YourController is another controller in admin controller folder
            echo YourController::test(); // test is action in YourController
     }
 }
```

Comment: In this case I have to put `Yii::import` in every action in all controllers. Isn't there a better way for this? What if I have 30 controllers and very many action methods? This is error prone

Comment: if you do not like to use import I suggest you for using AJAX request from view file....

Comment: Could you give and example to pull new Messages on every 10 sec?